# makefile not compiling correctly

Tags: c, makefile

I have a make file that is not compiling correctly and I can not figure out why. Here is my file:

```
comp = gcc
comp_flags = -g -Wall 
comp_libs = -lm  
#comp = cc

lab6 : graph_support.o lab6.o
    $(comp) $(comp_flags) graph_support.o lab6.o -o lab6 $(comp_libs)

graph.o : graph_support.c graph.h
    $(comp) $(comp_flags) -c graph_support.c

lab6.o : lab6.c graph.h
    $(comp) $(comp_flags) -c lab6.c

clean :
    rm -f *.o lab6 core
```

Now here is what happens when I make it:

```
cc    -c -o graph_support.o graph_support.c
gcc -g -Wall  graph_support.o lab6.o -o lab6 -lm
```

The second one works correctly but the first one doesnt have the correct comp and comp_flags.

Any reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You not tell to make anything about object file `graph_support.o`, so it decided to compile it with default rules (more information: `man make`, `make -p`, [gnu docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html)).

So, you probably need to change graph.o:

```
graph.o : graph_support.c graph.h
    $(comp) $(comp_flags) -c graph_support.c
```

to graph_support.o:

```
graph_support.o : graph_support.c graph.h
    $(comp) $(comp_flags) -c graph_support.c
```

Usually make used with default (implicit) rules. You can add compile flags to CFLAGS variable (instead of comp_flags) and you will not need rules like

```
graph_support.o : graph_support.c
...
lab6.o : lab6.c
...
```